# How to break on a clipboard operation in cmd.exe with IDA / WinDbg?

Tags: ida, windows, debugging, windbg

My goal is to see what's going on "under the hood" in the Windows command prompt when a user pastes text into it. So I loaded `cmd.exe` into IDA Pro that is set up in conjunction with the WinDbg debugger.

My initial guess was to put a breakpoint on [OpenClipboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649048(v=vs.85).aspx) API which must be used to access clipboard, but it seems like cmd.exe doesn't even have a dependency on `User32.dll` (where OpenClipboard comes from):

[image]

So am I reading it correctly?

PS. I'm doing this on Windows 10.

**EDIT:** You know, there's something other than deferred loading. I let the `cmd.exe` initialize and begin running, after which I suspended it. The loaded modules list still didn't have `user32.dll`:

[image]

and my deferred breakpoint didn't trigger upon clipboard operation either:

[image]

Could there be some other process that does all the "command line" logic?

**EDIT 2:** Just tried to attach to a running `conhost.exe`:

[image]

while IDA Pro was running as administrator and got this error:

[image]

**EDIT 3:** Just tried to attach to `conhost.exe` via just WinDbg itself and got this error. I'm not sure how `NTSTATUS 0xC00000BB` applies here:

[image]

Comment: Using `depends.exe` on `cmd.exe` in syswow64 shows `user32.dll` as a delayed loaded module. I assume your screenshot only shows the currently loaded modules thus the discrepency.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers: Sorry for the delay. I updated my original question with additional info. And delayed loading doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: looks like you're using x86 windbg to attach to an x64 process :) This is not going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well if you cant attach with windbg then you have some other problem
`uac / clamped down / policy / whatever //` conhost.exe is attachable
(check if you are attaching to the correct conhost.exe there may be several some of them spawned by `system user`

screenshot showing windbg being attached to conhost and broke on OpenClipBoard with Hwnd (HANDLE of consoleWindowClass)

[image]

on the paste operation

```
0:001> kb2
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
00 020afc28 00adf554 020afd34 00000111 00000000 conhost!DoPaste+0x3d
01 020afcb8 773ec4e7 00080260 00000111 0000fff1 conhost!ConsoleWindowProc+0x847
0:001> ub eip l1
conhost!DoPaste+0x37:
00ae2d05 ff155411ad00    call    dword ptr [conhost!_imp__GetClipboardData (00ad1154)]
0:001> ? @$retreg
Evaluate expression: 10616892 = 00a2003c
0:001> du poi(@$retreg)
00172fa0  "2580 windbg.exe        Pid 3424 "
00172fe0  "- WinDbg:10.0.10586.567 X86"
0:001> g
```

as to comment yes maybe i dont know
a cursory glance over google says conhost is now a child of cmd in windows 10
the conhost enhancements technical preview article by some ms devs don't mention anything about conhost being `protected super proteccted or ultra protected process`
and i dont have a win10 handy so i can answer your comment only when i spleunk under winX till then happy hunting

well it appears i can attach in winX too
(winx is running in vmware player  (test mode ) ) 
windbg screen shotted is runnning inside target os

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, that's the right process. I checked. It was spawned right when cmd.exe was started. I updated my original post with the error message I got in WinDbg. BTW. I'm doing it on Win10. You're using Win7. Could that be the difference?

Comment: no dont see any logic difference between vii and x  apart from some new dlls / functions //control flow   from console to core APIS

Comment: OK. I got it solved... somewhat. I was using IDA Pro to start the process and then WinDbg thru it. It turns out that IDA Pro cannot attach to a 64-bit process so it was using a 32-bit version of WinDbg implicitly. Thus I was getting that strange error. I also discovered that I was using an old version of WinDbg. And lastly, even though I was originally starting a 32-bit version of `cmd.exe` it was implicitly connecting to a 64-bit version of `conhost.exe`. So eventually I had to ditch IDA and go with bare WinDbg which is somewhat hard to use... but it did the job. So thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The actual console window is drawn and managed by conhost.exe, not cmd.exe.
[image: conhost.exe calling OpenClipboard]

Comment: Sorry, I'm somewhat new to this. Can you give more details on how you set that breakpoint?

Comment: attach to `conhost.exe`, pause, switch to asm (Alt-8), enter `user32.dll!OpenClipboard` in the address field, add breakpoint from asm listing. But VS is not very good debugger when you don't have source, I recommend you to use Windbg or IDA.

Comment: Thanks. Tried to attach to `conhost.exe` and got access denied error. I updated my question w/details. Any idea why am I getting that error?